# Delete VisualForce page from production

Tags: visualforce

How does one delete a VF page from production?  There is no delete button there.  Is it possible to delete it from a sandbox and somehow migrate the deletion to production?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Propagating_Destructive_Changes

Comment: Nominated for reopening because the VF Page should be deletable from the UI in production. The OP does not see the DEL link and while it is most likely a permission issue it does not appear to be a duplicate of the question indicated int he comments

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to delete Visualforce pages from production directly and there should be a link to delete as long as you have the appropriate permissions and it is not a managed package.....

Simply goto:

Setup -> Develop -> Pages

Find the page you want to delete and click the DEL link.

If it is not there, ensure you have the proper permissions (`Customize Application`) and it is not a component of a managed package.

Answer (score 1):

There is a concept called destructive changes, where you would need to run a deployment where you include the files you want to delete.

Check [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/daas_destructive_changes.htm) for further details

Comment: Unless something has changed a VF page can be deleted directly from production via the UI. This means the answer is unnecessarily complex